# sub spaces of vector spaces problems

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, invariant-subspace

> Let $W, U_1, U_2$ be sub spaces of linear spaces $V$. It is said that $$\ V = U_1 \oplus U_2 $$
>
> 1. Prove that if $\ U_1 \subseteq W$ , then $W=U_1 \oplus(U_2\cap W) .$
> 2. Give an example of a linear space V and sub spaces $U_1, U_2, W $ so that $V = U_1\oplus U_2$ and $ W \neq(U_1 \cap W) \oplus (U_2\cap W). $
> 3. $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k,u,w$ are vectors in linear space $V$. It is said that $x_1 v_1+x_2v_2+...+x_k v_k = u$ has a single solution and that $x_1 v_1+x_2v_2+...+x_k v_k = w$ has no solution.
>    Find the dimension of $\operatorname{SP}\left\lbrace v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k,w\right\rbrace$.

I'm having a real hard time and I hope that by helping and showing me the correct way I'll be able to learn and become better.

I understand that if $W,U_1,U_2$ are subspaces of V, and that V=U1⊕U2 and that W should be $U_1$ + $W-U_2$ (since  V=U1⊕U2 and that U1⊆W) but i don't know how to explain it correctly mathmatically. i don't know how to prove that in a correct manner, that's why i asked for help.

Comment: For 2: try $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, $U_1 = \langle (1, 0) \rangle$, $U_2 = \langle (0, 1) \rangle$, $W = \langle (1, 1) \rangle$.

Comment: For 1: take $v \in W- U_1$  since $v \in V$ it follows that $v\in U_2$. So you have $W-U_1 \subset U_2$ Since $U_1$ and $U_2$ are disjoint the intersection of $U_2$ and $W$ is $W-U_1$

Comment: @Cerkal I don't see what $v \in W - U_1$ has to do with anything - this is referring to direct sum of subspaces, not a disjoint union of subsets.

Comment: Hint for 1: To show $W \subseteq U_1 + (U_2 \cap W)$: suppose $x \in W$.  Since $V = U_1 \oplus U_2$, there are $y \in U_1$ and $z \in U_2$ such that $x = y + z$.  Now what can you conclude about $y$ and $z$, respectively?

Comment: @Daniel Schepler you do direct sum. it need to be that they are disjoint.

Comment: @Cerkal It's impossible for two subspaces to be disjoint since they both contain 0.  $V = U_1 \oplus U_2$ means $U_1 \cap U_2 = \{ 0 \}$ and $U_1 + U_2 = V$.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler yes yes i actually mean {0} by saying disjoint sorry my fault.

Comment: LinearProblems:  I see your missing context in your post?  Please add what you attempted, and/or add the information you think might apply to each of your questions (definitions, e.g.). This is not a homework completion site.  Since you're "glad you joined"  you should familiarize yourself with site expectations.

Comment: Also, commenters:  I certainly do not see the asker in the discussion above.

Comment: Daniel, i don't understand your way, and i don't understand how you can conclude about y and z. please explain